# SQL computed column, recursively summarizing a hierarchy

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, recursive-query, calculated-columns

The [simplified] story so far:

In a .mdf DB under Visual Studio 2010, I have a the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SandTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [isDone] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [percentComplete]  AS ([dbo].[CompletePercent]([id],[isDone])),
    [parentId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SandTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SandTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SandTable_SandTable] FOREIGN KEY([parentId])
```

The idea is that rows are formed as a tree/forest, with parentId used as a 'pointer' to the parent node.

The 'percentComplete' computed column uses the function CompletePercent to calculate how much of the sub-tree, rooted at the row, is complete, as follows:

- If a row's 'isDone' bit is 1, then we consider the entire sub-tree to be 100% complete (this is a user-override), and so return 1.0.
- However, if 'isDone' is 0, I need to calculate the entire sub-tree's 'completeness'. I do this by recursively averaging the 'completeness' of the direct children, which do so for their children, and so forth until the leaves.

At first, I tried to have 'CompletePercent' average the direct-children's 'percentComplete' column. However, as I discovered (and later confirmed online), computed columns cannot be used as part of a computed column's calculation.

Currently I am frustrated by always getting 1 for 'isDone'=1 rows, and 0 for 'isDone'=0 rows, using the following implementation of CompletePercent:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CompletePercent]
    (
    @id int, 
    @isDone bit = 0
    )
RETURNS float
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @result float
        IF @isDone = 1
            SET @result = 1.0
        ELSE
            SET @result = 
                (SELECT 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (COUNT(*) = 0) THEN 0.0
                        ELSE AVG(dbo.CompletePercent(id, isDone))
                    END
                FROM dbo.SandTable
                WHERE parentId = @id
                )
        RETURN @result
    END
```

I hope there is something simple here I'm just missing, from staring at it for so long.

My next step is to try using a recursive CTE, which I'm researching at the moment. However, I'm not really sure how to code the 'special' conditional averaging required.

If anyone can spot the mistake in my actions to date, or guide me in the CTE direction, I'd be very grateful.

*[EDIT:]* I have come to a dead end even on the CTE track, with the following crazy (and probably wasteful, if it could run) query:

```
WITH Weights AS (SELECT SandTable.id, COUNT(NULLIF (SandTable.isDone, 0)) AS isDone, 100.0 AS weight, COUNT(ST.id) AS kids
    FROM SandTable INNER JOIN
        SandTable AS ST ON SandTable.id = ST.parentId
    WHERE (SandTable.parentId IS NULL)
    GROUP BY SandTable.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SandTable_1.id, COUNT(NULLIF (SandTable_1.isDone, 0)) AS isDone, MyCTE_2.weight / MyCTE_2.kids AS weight, COUNT(ST_1.id) AS kids
    FROM SandTable AS SandTable_1 INNER JOIN
        MyCTE AS MyCTE_2 ON SandTable_1.parentId = MyCTE_2.id AND MyCTE_2.isDone = 0 INNER JOIN
        SandTable AS ST_1 ON SandTable.id = ST_1.parentId
    WHERE (SandTable_1.parentId IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY SandTable_1.id)
 SELECT SUM(weight)
    FROM Weights AS Weights_1
    WHERE (isDone > 0)
```

The idea was to travel down the hierarchy (currently from the root, but I planned to modify it to start with a specific id), and for each node count the number of children and test for 'isDone' (done here as an aggregate to account for the JOIN used to perform the count, now isDone is considered 'true' in the CTE's result if it is not 0). The 'weight' (really the % it contributes to the total) of each node is it's parent's weight divided by the number of its siblings (including itself), with the root set as 100%.

The trip down is stopped either for an 'isDone' node, or at a leaf. Both of which will have the next recursive step return 0 rows).

Finally, the total weight of the 'idDone' nodes is summed (the other nodes were only there for the recursion).

However, this fails to run because, as the resulting error states:
"GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate funcitons are not allowed in the recursive part pf a recursive common table expression".

Again, any hint on making any headway in any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
ShaiB

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? ("*Visual Studio 2010*" is just a client application, it doesn't tell us anything about your database)

Comment: Sorry for not specifying this: I have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my development machine. I am editing everything through VS's server explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be a fairly expensive operation, no matter the route you choose. But, here are some ideas that might help:

First, have you thought about using a view? You could drop the computed column on the table and add it onto the view, which would probably let you get around the computed column constraints. You could also make the view updatable (via instead-of triggers), so that to your application it behaves like a table.

Second, you could do this via stored procedures. Use a cursor to iterate through the base table one row at a time, compute the value of the `percentComplete` column, and store the result in a table variable. (You could probably write this in such a way that you only have to visit each row in the base table once.) Then simply return (ie, SELECT) the results from the table variable.

Third, similar to the second, write a trigger to re-compute the `percentComplete` for each row after inserts/updates/deletes, instead of using a computed column. While this would give you very fast reads, it'd probably be very slow on writes.

Fourth, you could probably do this via CLR function (ie, write it in C# and import it into the server). You can get away with breaking a lot of SQL Server's (goofy) rules for functions with CLR functions. (Although, that doesn't mean it's always a good idea.)

Fifth, and probably most complicated, you could write a CLR table function to read the rows from the table (without the `percentComplete`) and compute and append the `percentComplete` column to the result set. Then, use this as the basis for a view (ie, `SELECT * FROM dbo.GetTheTree()`) and then use instead-of triggers to make the view updatable (similar to the second option).

Hope that gives you some ideas!